# QBSDK invoice query

Tags: vb.net, quickbooks, invoice

I am using vb.net in visual studio to query my invoices.
i get a list of invoice of interest, and as i iterate through the list, i see the for each invoice i have, the invoice.ORInvoiceLineRetList is nothing.
here is a snippet of code, although i *think* i am doing everything right?

```
resp = SessMgr.DoRequests(msgReq)
resplist = resp.ResponseList
curResp = resplist.GetAt(0)
If curResp.StatusCode = 0 Then
    Dim invoiceList As IInvoiceRetList = curResp.Detail
    Dim curInvoice As IInvoiceRet
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To invoiceList.Count - 1
        curInvoice = invoiceList.GetAt(i)
```

if i breakpoint right after the last line, i see curInvoice, and its data (e.g. refnumber), but i need to get to the line items.
can someone help?
Thanks,
Jerry

Comment: There's an "Include line items" boolean you need to set as part of your IInvoiceQuery. If I have time later I'll write it up as an answer

Answer (score 4):

If your IInvoiceQuery is called invoiceQuery, add this (just replace invoice query with your IInvoiceQuery objects name if it's called something else)

```
invoiceQuery.IncludeLineItems.SetValue(True)
```

before this

```
resp = SessMgr.DoRequests(msgReq)
```

and that should fix your problem

Comment: FANTASTIC! i totally missed that flag.